# Is there a proven causality that energy-matter causes curvature in spacetime?

Tags: energy, spacetime, mass, causality

I'm not very knowledgable in physics, sorry.

I've read and (somewhat) understood that energy-matter causes space-time to curve but I was wondering about the causality in the statement.

Is this causality proven? (My guess based on the prevalence of the formulation is yes, if so and if you have any easy resources that explains it I would be super happy with a link or explanation).
If not, are there theories that flip the causality?
Or maybe others that argues that it be understood as one phenomenon i.e without any meaning of casualy in the statement?
Or that the causality is unknown or even indeterminate?

I've tried some (rudimentary) searching but the explanations haven't focused on the causality aspect so I thought I'd ask. Thanks!

Comment: Victor Stenger wrote a book about "backward causality" and "time symmetric causality", on the quantum level, called Timeless Reality. I don't know how speculative it is. But it's a good book.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should clarify that by flipping the causality I meant in the statement like so: "Curvature in space time causes mass to emerge". And with the one phenomenon phrase I meant "Curvature in space time and mass-energy is not two separate things"

Comment: Generally speaking, when we write basic physical laws like "$X = Y$" we don't mean that $X$ causes $Y$, or that $Y$ causes $X$. We just mean they happen to be equal in nature. Causality is a concept that emerges in macroscopic systems (like "I caused the house of cards to fall") but at the most microscopic level, we just have mathematical identities.

Comment: Suppose for example that you gave me a dollar. The decrease in my wealth is precisely each to the increase in my wealth -- that is a mathematical identity. But which of these things caused the other? The question simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: It is sometimes the case, though, that in laws of the form $X = Y$, you usually know $X$, and then use the law to figure out what $Y$ is. In that case, sometimes people say $X$ causes $Y$, but it's not a rigorous statement. If you knew $Y$ you could just as easily use the law to determine $X$.

Comment: Thanks knzhou! Then I know (provided other answers doesn't contest it) that the causality in the phrase isn't to be taken at face value but is a description of correlation rather than causality. (Edit: maybe correlation is a to week word, connection would maybe be more suitable)

Comment: @JoelP It is a fundamental assumption of GR, ordinary classical GR without QM, that causal curves are timelike or null; they're in or on the lightcone. But weird things happen when QM comes into it. Like at the event horizon of a black hole. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRbclaA53HM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To posit a causal relationship between states is to posit an arrangement in time and space in which one state is in the [causal past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) of the other, and that in arrangements in spacetime in which states of the putatively causal type are not part of the causal past, states of putatively caused type are not found.

A hypothetical experiment determining whether mass-energy was a cause of its associated spacetime curvature would seek evidence of some mass-energy that at some time $t_1$ was not correlated with spacetime curvature and at some later time $t_2$ it was. (Or at least something similar enough to mass-energy that we could recognize it as such, despite its lack of associated spacetime curvature.) Relativity does not predict such a phenomenon.

This is not unusual. Mechanics does not predict forces causing accelerations or accelerations causing forces, for example. Force is modeled as a particular mathematical configuration of position, time, and mass variables, any of which could, in principle, be expressed as a mathematical configuration of force and the other variables. The stress-energy tensor is a more complicated mathematical configuration of a larger number of variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's a model. It makes predictions. Those predictions have been tested multiple times in a variety of situations. The test results match the model predictions. That's as good as it gets in physics.

Comment: Maybe proven is the wrong word to use, sorry about that. Maybe it can be rephrased as: Does the model predict the causality of the relation or only the correlation?

Comment: @JoelP What experiment would you propose to answer your question?

Comment: Haha I have no idea. My question was in part if such an experiment has been done. I take it from your stance that the answer is no. And from @knzhou above I gather that the term "causes" in the statement isn't to be taken at face value but describes a inherit connection rather than a causal relation